# CSS file interaction in W3C's validation service

Tags: css, w3c-validation

I'm working with the W3C's CSS validator. The validator will take an HTML page and check all its inline, embedded, & linked CSS.

Is it safe to validate all my CSS separately (validate the inline / embedded CSS without the linked CSS being available etc.)?

Is there anything the validator can error check better when all the elements of the CSS for a page are validated together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The W3C validator only checks the syntax of your markup so it is fine to check CSS rules separately.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is anything that the validator could say better with all the files at once, except maybe that some of your classes or Id's in your html do not have styles in your CSS, but thats perfectly valid anyway. On a side note, why are you so worried that your page is perfectly valid?

Comment: > why are you so worried that your page is perfectly valid?

Should have made this clear, I'm actually developing a validation service.